# NGRX: from @Effect to createEffect

Tags: ngrx, effect

I have update my Angular app and now I need to convert some code. What is the translation from `@Effect` to `createEffect` for the following code, please?

```
@Effect()
getTasks$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(taskActions.LOAD_ACCOUNTS_TASKS),
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.rest.get(`${tasksUrl}`).pipe(
            map((response) => new taskActions.LoadTasksSuccess(response)),
            catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => of(err.status === 401 ?
                new oauthActions.FailedRequestWith401(new taskActions.LoadTasks()) :
                new taskActions.LoadTasksFail()
            ))
        );
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much mystery to it, you just wrap it actions observable in a `createEffect` factory function:

```
 getTasks$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(taskActions.LOAD_ACCOUNTS_TASKS),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.rest.get(`${tasksUrl}`).pipe(
          map((response) => new taskActions.LoadTasksSuccess(response)),
          catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) =>
            of(
              err.status === 401
                ? new oauthActions.FailedRequestWith401(new taskActions.LoadTasks())
                : new taskActions.LoadTasksFail()
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```